# Using cherrypy.lib.sessions.expire

Tags: cherrypy

My cherrypy class definition includes the method:

```
@cherrypy expose
def quit(self)
   cherrypy.lib.sessions.expire(self)
   return "Session closed"
```

My goal is to reset the current session. However, this function call returns "Missing module name". Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my question! I made a confusion. ;-(